# How to get the number of all possible combinations of k positive integers to reach a given product?

Tags: number-theory, combinations

Let $n_1,\cdots,n_k$ be $k$ positive integers and $k>2$. Given that $\prod_{i=1}^kn_i=N$, how would you find all combinations of $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$? Here the order does matter. For example， when $k=3$, $(2,3,2)$ and $(2,2,3)$ are different.

Btw, I just was stuck in the first step: finding the prime factorization of $N=\prod_{j=1}^mp_j^{q_j}$, where all $p_j$ are prime numbers and $q_j\geq1$, and the the number of combinations can be expressed in the form of something related with $q_j$.

For example, in the $k=3$ case, I got a solution: the number is $\prod_{j=1}^m \tbinom{1+q_j}{2}$. But I cannot get the idea how to get such conclustion. Anyone know the detailed derivation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider just one prime that divides $N$, but with some reasonable power.  In the $k=3$ case, you can put the prime factors into any of the three numbers that will multiply to $N$.  For example, if $p^4$ is the highest factor of some prime $p$ that divides $N$, you are looking for three numbers (with $0$ allowed) that sum to $4$.  This is what [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) addresses.  There are ${5 \choose 2}=10$ weak compositions of $4$ into three pieces.  Each prime dividing $N$ gets treated the same:  you want the number of weak compositions of the exponent of the prime into $k$ pieces, then as the composition of the factors of each prime is chosen separately, you multiply them.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I thought the stars and bars stuff by the way: I put every $p_j$ together without distinction, so I was stuck to find an approviate multiplicative partition of $\tbinom{1+q_1+...+q_m}{2}$. Thank you so much again!